# Connecting to a DB2 Client, Toad did not find a default 64bit db2 client

Tags: db2, toad

I get the following error when i open Toad:

[image: This message shows up when Toad Starts]

However, I have a default DB2 Client installed on windows and the DB2 client version is 11 which is required by toad.

This is the screenshot of Registry Editor HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\IBM\DB2 and the default DB2 client is the required driver:
[image: Registry Editor]

and in toad there is no default DB2 Client referenced and the list is empty:
[image: Toad Settings]

environment variables:

[image]

Comment: Why does it say "Toad for DB2 7.1"?

Comment: the error message shows up for Toad 7.1 and Toad 6.5.

Comment: @Ezzat Toad v7.1 on windows 8.1 x64 automatically finds my Db2 runtime client when it starts up.   EDIT your question to show whether the runtime client directories are automatically on your system PATH  environment variable before Toad-for-Db2 starts.

Comment: You have some configuration issue specific to your environment. Suggest you try on different workstations, and/or uninstall Toad and the runtime client fully,  reboot, and re-install both. If you cannot progress, open a ticket with Quest (if you have a support contract). Otherwise , use the latest v11.1.4.5 runtime client (i.e. fixpack 5)  for x64 (which is what I use) , or use the Microsoft sysinternals process explorer to debug what is happening.

Comment: Also, (for testing purposes) in the environment variable for PATH, move the runtime client directories so they appear at the start of the path and not at the end. The idea is to eliminate any possibility that there is more than one set of DLLs for Db2 that can confuse Toad. After you make this change, *reboot* and then retry toad-for-db2.

Comment: I tried both solutions but error keeps showing up.

Comment: EDIT your question to add your MS-Windows edition and version (text only, not graphic image), Add whether the Windows is running in a VM or on a laptop. Have you tried on different workstations? Are you able to debug with Process-Explorer?  Have you opened a case with Quest support?